# How to assert django uses particular template in pytest

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

In the `unittest` style, I can test that a page uses a particular template by calling [`assertTemplateUsed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/test/testcases/#SimpleTestCase.assertTemplateUsed). This is useful, for example, when Django inserts values through a template, so that I can't just test string equality.

How should I write the equivalent statement in pytest?

I've been looking in [pytest-django](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) but don't see how to do it.

Comment: I dont understand your question you want to test that the data that you pass to a template is correctly rendered?

Comment: @Augustin No, I want to test that when I get a page, it's using the template file I expect it to use.

Comment: If you get the "Page" then you are getting the template, if not, what do you mean by getting a "page"? Could you provide some sort of code so I can help you out?

Comment: The code for [assertTemplateUsed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/test/testcases/#SimpleTestCase.assertTemplateUsed) and `_assert_template_used` show there is an attribute `.templates` in `reponse`. So you need something like `assert response.templates and ('mytemplate' in [t.name for t in response.templates if t.name is not None])`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) stated in a comment, use the following to assert that a template file is actually used in a view:

```
response = client.get(article.get_absolute_url())
assert 'article_detail.html' in (t.name for t in response.templates)
```

Update: Since v3.8.0 (2020-01-14) pytest-django makes all of the assertions in Django's TestCase available in `pytest_django.asserts`. See [Stan Redoute's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62551690/219519)
for an example.

Comment: This a workaround rather than actual solution to the problem.

Comment: Why do you say that? It's what Django does in `assertTemplateUsed()`. Wrap it in a function and that's it. What more do you want for it to not be a "workaround"?

Comment: Maybe “workaround” was an overstatement, however there’s a dedicated assertion provided by `pytest_django`.

Answer (score 19):

To assert whether given template was used to render specific view you can (and even should) use helpers provided by `pytest-django`:

```
import pytest
from pytest_django.asserts import assertTemplateUsed

...

def test_should_use_correct_template_to_render_a_view(client):
    response = client.get('.../your-url/')
    assertTemplateUsed(response, 'template_name.html')
```

`pytest-django` even uses this exact assertion as an example in [documentation](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html?highlight=assertTemplateUsed#assertions).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand clearly, you want to test if Django renders the data that you pass to the template correctly. If this is the case, then the concepts are wrong, you should test the data gathered in your view first, and then make sure it calls the template. Testing that the template contains the correct data would be testing Django framework itself.